# Event when window.location.href changes

Tags: javascript, dom, greasemonkey, dom-events

I'm writing a Greasemonkey script for a site which at some point modifies `location.href`.

How can I get an event (via `window.addEventListener` or something similar) when `window.location.href` changes on a page? I also need access to the DOM of the document pointing to the new/modified url.

I've seen other solutions which involve timeouts and polling, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: For YouTube: [javascript - How to detect page navigation on YouTube and modify HTML before page is rendered? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077641/how-to-detect-page-navigation-on-youtube-and-modify-html-before-page-is-rendered)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

[popstate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate):

> The popstate event is fired when the active history entry changes.  [...] The popstate event is only triggered by doing a browser action such as a click on the back button (or calling history.back() in JavaScript)

So, listening to `popstate` event and sending a `popstate` event when using `history.pushState()` should be enough to take action on `href` change:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', listener);

const pushUrl = (href) => {
  history.pushState({}, '', href);
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('popstate'));
};
```

Comment: But will the popstate fire before the content is loaded?

Comment: unusable if don't have any control over the piece of code that `pushState`

Comment: This does not always work, it relies on a popstate event to be fired. For example navigating within youtube it won't trigger, only if you press back or forward in history

Comment: this assume you have visibility or know if pushState is called.. it won't work everywhere, like comments above state as well

Comment: If you don't control the callers of `history.pushState`, then you can instead override `history.pushState` with a function that delegates to the original function, then calls your `listener` function.

Comment: Fixed URL... MDN is acting up...: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event

Answer (score 201):

I use this script in my extension "Grab Any Media" and work fine ( *like youtube case* )

```js
var oldHref = document.location.href;

window.onload = function() {
    var bodyList = document.querySelector("body")

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        if (oldHref != document.location.href) {
            oldHref = document.location.href;
            /* Changed ! your code here */
        }
    });
    
    var config = {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    };
    
    observer.observe(bodyList, config);
};
```

**With the latest javascript specification**

```
const observeUrlChange = () => {
  let oldHref = document.location.href;
  const body = document.querySelector("body");
  const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    if (oldHref !== document.location.href) {
      oldHref = document.location.href;
      /* Changed ! your code here */
    }
  });
  observer.observe(body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
};

window.onload = observeUrlChange;
```

Comment: The only solution that could have worked for youtube:  [Report Only] Refused to create a worker from 'https://www.youtube.com/sw.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "worker-src 'none'".

Comment: MutationObserver

Comment: Worked out of the box with no trouble for my use case, God bless! It's annoying there's no native event for this yet (popstate did not work for me) but one day! I would use `window.addEventListener("load", () => {})` instead of window.onload though :)

Comment: this works, detects history.pushState even in extension context

Comment: This is the smartest solution to this problem (listening for changes in the body). Also works within React to detect URL changes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: put this in content script but it is not firing.

Comment: Hello I am new to using MutationObservers and love this solution,its the only one I found that worked sofar for YT redirects. Just wanted to note that you could make it more efficient by moving the `if (oldHref != document.location.href)` check before your `forEach` call as you would only need to do the check once.

Comment: This doesn't work if I just click a link, it changes the location but the body itself doesn't change instantly, only after some user interaction.

Comment: You are not allowed to reassign to variables declared with `const`; it needs to be `let oldHref = ''` for it to work. Also, you could save space by passing `document.body` directly, instead of declaring a variable for that.  But thanks for the innovative use of MutationObserver (if anything in the DOM changes, check if the URL changed also => clever :) ).

Comment: Safari doesn't seem to honor the first call

Comment: This is the best way to do this as far as I have seen. The Navigator API is not ready and isn't working well on browsers it is support. The only problem was `body` has too many triggers, so I reduced to an element that I know will always be present and has child changes whenever route changes. Others note that this is not only meant for body, it can work with any element in the DOM, but you can narrow it down to something that always changes or even attributes.

Answer (score 42):

You can't avoid polling, there isn't any event for href change.

Using intervals is quite light anyways if you don't go overboard. Checking the href every 50ms or so will not have any significant effect on performance if you're worried about that.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: fortunately there are these new solutions of `popstate` and `hashchange`.

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: @MartinZvarík Even in 2010 it was possible to use the unload event plus a micro or macro task to get the new document loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is still correct in 2020. [popstate only fires when the user uses the forward/back buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14150776/5776910) and hashchange only fires for hash changes. Unless you have control over the code that's causing the location to change, you have to poll ‍♀️

Comment: @RicoKahler yep, i tested and saw the same, `popsate` & `hashchange` don't work with some app frameworks, the url does change as seen but these 2 are not fired

Answer (score 34):

In supporting browsers, use the new [Navigation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_API) which is currently being implemented as a replacement for the History API:

```
navigation.addEventListener('navigate', () => {
  console.log('page changed');
});
```

This already works in Chromium browsers, but Firefox and Safari are currently missing it as of January 2024.

It simplifies the problem considerably, and is being designed specifically with single page applications in mind which is the main sore spot with existing solutions. No more nasty expensive `MutationObserver` calls!

Comment: if you only ever use chrome

Comment: well it doesn't look that bad if you don't need Firefox and Safari :D

Answer (score 28):

There is a default `onhashchange` event that you can use.

[Documented HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)

And can be used like this:

```
function locationHashChanged( e ) {
    console.log( location.hash );
    console.log( e.oldURL, e.newURL );
    if ( location.hash === "#pageX" ) {
        pageX();
    }
}

window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```

If the browser doesn't support `oldURL` and `newURL` you can bind it like this:

```
//let this snippet run before your hashChange event binding code
if( !window.HashChangeEvent )( function() {
    let lastURL = document.URL;
    window.addEventListener( "hashchange", function( event ) {
        Object.defineProperty( event, "oldURL", { enumerable: true, configurable: true, value: lastURL } );
        Object.defineProperty( event, "newURL", { enumerable: true, configurable: true, value: document.URL } );
        lastURL = document.URL;
    } );
} () );
```

Comment: Hashchange events are only sent if your URL has a part starting with a '#' symbol, normally used for anchor links. 
Otherwise it won't fire.

Comment: window.addEventListener("hashchange", funcRef, false);

Answer (score 14):

Through **Jquery**, just try

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    //your code goes here on location change 
});
```

By using **javascript**:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
   //your code goes here on location change 
});
```

Refer Document : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Comment: Just try it, doesn't work on Firefox.

Comment: it's working, use javascript

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried beforeUnload?
This event fires immediately before the page responds to a navigation request, and this should include the modification of the href.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE></TITLE>
    <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="TextPad 4.6">
    <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="?">
    <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="?">
    <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="?">
    </HEAD>

         <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(window).unload(
                        function(event) {
                            alert("navigating");
                        }
                );
                $("#theButton").click(
                    function(event){
                        alert("Starting navigation");
                        window.location.href = "http://www.bbc.co.uk";
                    }
                );

            });
            </script>


    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000" LINK="#FF0000" VLINK="#800000" ALINK="#FF00FF" BACKGROUND="?">

        <button id="theButton">Click to navigate</button>

        <a href="http://www.google.co.uk"> Google</a>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Beware, however, that your event will fire ***whenever*** you navigate away from the page, whether this is because of the script, or somebody clicking on a link.
Your real challenge, is detecting the different reasons for the event being fired. (If this is important to your logic)

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work because often the hash changes do no involve a page reload.

Comment: I need access to the new DOM as well, I updated the question to clarify that.

Comment: OK - didn't consider the `hash` situation - will think about that one.
As for being able to access the new DOM, then you are out of luck (as far as accesssing this from an event handler is concerned) as the event will fire before the new DOM has been loaded. You might be able to incorporate the logic into the onload event of the new page, but you may have the same issues with respect to identifying whether you need to carry out the logic for every load of that page.
Can you provide some more details about what you are trying to achieve, including page flow?

Comment: I just tried accessing the location.href inside the onbeforeunload event handler, and it shows the original url, not the target url.

Comment: Beforeunload can cancel the unloading of the page, so the unload event is better, if you don't want to cancel navigation.

Answer (score 7):

Try this script which will let you run code whenever the URL changes (without a pageload, like an Single Page Application):

```js
var previousUrl = '';
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  if (location.href !== previousUrl) {
      previousUrl = location.href;
      console.log(`URL changed to ${location.href}`);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

> **ReactJS and other SPA** applications use the `history` object

You can listen to `window.history` updating with the following code:

```
function watchHistoryEvents() {
    const { pushState, replaceState } = window.history;

    window.history.pushState = function (...args) {
        pushState.apply(window.history, args);
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('pushState'));
    };

    window.history.replaceState = function (...args) {
        replaceState.apply(window.history, args);
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('replaceState'));
    };

    window.addEventListener('popstate', () => console.log('popstate event'));
    window.addEventListener('replaceState', () => console.log('replaceState event'));
    window.addEventListener('pushState', () => console.log('pushState event'));
}
watchHistoryEvents();
```

Comment: When use forward button of the browser this does not catch any event.

Answer (score 6):

based on the answer from "Leonardo Ciaccio", modified code is here:
i.e. removed for loop and reassign the Body Element if it is removed

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  let oldHref = document.location.href,
    bodyDOM = document.querySelector("body");
  function checkModifiedBody() {
    let tmp = document.querySelector("body");
    if (tmp != bodyDOM) {
      bodyDOM = tmp;
      observer.observe(bodyDOM, config);
    }
  }
  const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    if (oldHref != document.location.href) {
      oldHref = document.location.href;
      console.log("the location href is changed!");
      window.requestAnimationFrame(checkModifiedBody)
    }
  });
  const config = {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  };
  observer.observe(bodyDOM, config);
}, false);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: This is a very complete answer!

Answer (score 4):

Well there is 2 ways to change the `location.href`. Either you can write `location.href = "y.html"`, which reloads the page or can use the history API which does not reload the page. I experimented with the first a lot recently.

If you open a child window and capture the load of the child page from the parent window, then different browsers behave very differently. The only thing that is common, that they remove the old document and add a new one, so for example adding readystatechange or load event handlers to the old document does not have any effect. Most of the browsers remove the event handlers from the window object too, the only exception is Firefox. In Chrome with Karma runner and in Firefox you can capture the new document in the loading readyState if you use `unload + next tick`. So you can add for example a load event handler or a readystatechange event handler or just log that the browser is loading a page with a new URI. In Chrome with manual testing (probably GreaseMonkey too) and in Opera, PhantomJS, IE10, IE11 you cannot capture the new document in the loading state. In those browsers the `unload + next tick` calls the callback a few hundred msecs later than the load event of the page fires. The delay is typically 100 to 300 msecs, but opera simetime makes a 750 msec delay for next tick, which is scary. So if you want a consistent result in all browsers, then you do what you want to after the load event, but there is no guarantee the location won't be overridden before that.

```
var uuid = "win." + Math.random();
var timeOrigin = new Date();
var win = window.open("about:blank", uuid, "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");


var callBacks = [];
var uglyHax = function (){
    var done = function (){
        uglyHax();
        callBacks.forEach(function (cb){
            cb();
        });
    };
    win.addEventListener("unload", function unloadListener(){
        win.removeEventListener("unload", unloadListener); // Firefox remembers, other browsers don't
        setTimeout(function (){
            // IE10, IE11, Opera, PhantomJS, Chrome has a complete new document at this point
            // Chrome on Karma, Firefox has a loading new document at this point
            win.document.readyState; // IE10 and IE11 sometimes fails if I don't access it twice, idk. how or why
            if (win.document.readyState === "complete")
                done();
            else
                win.addEventListener("load", function (){
                    setTimeout(done, 0);
                });
        }, 0);
    });
};
uglyHax();


callBacks.push(function (){
    console.log("cb", win.location.href, win.document.readyState);
    if (win.location.href !== "http://localhost:4444/y.html")
        win.location.href = "http://localhost:4444/y.html";
    else
        console.log("done");
});
win.location.href = "http://localhost:4444/x.html";
```

If you run your script only in Firefox, then you can use a simplified version and capture the document in a loading state, so for example a script on the loaded page cannot navigate away before you log the URI change:

```
var uuid = "win." + Math.random();
var timeOrigin = new Date();
var win = window.open("about:blank", uuid, "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");


var callBacks = [];
win.addEventListener("unload", function unloadListener(){
    setTimeout(function (){
        callBacks.forEach(function (cb){
            cb();
        });
    }, 0);
});


callBacks.push(function (){
    console.log("cb", win.location.href, win.document.readyState);
    // be aware that the page is in loading readyState, 
    // so if you rewrite the location here, the actual page will be never loaded, just the new one
    if (win.location.href !== "http://localhost:4444/y.html")
        win.location.href = "http://localhost:4444/y.html";
    else
        console.log("done");
});
win.location.href = "http://localhost:4444/x.html";
```

If we are talking about single page applications which change the hash part of the URI, or use the history API, then you can use the `hashchange` and the `popstate` events of the window respectively. Those can capture even if you move in history back and forward until you stay on the same page. The document does not changes by those and the page is not really reloaded.

Answer (score 4):

Also, I found a useful solution with `MutationObserver`:

```
function watchLocation() {
    const observable = () => document.location.pathname;

    let oldValue = observable();
    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
        const newValue = observable();

        if (oldValue !== newValue) {
            console.log(`changed: ${oldValue} -> ${newValue}`);
            oldValue = newValue;
        }
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
}
```

> [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) API Documantation

Comment: Safari doesn't seem to honor the first call.

Answer (score -2):

For React and React-router

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
const App = () => {
   const { pathname } = useLocation();
   useEffect(() => {
      /* handle the event when pathname change */
  }, [pathname]);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: where did the person who asked the question state they need with react router? please don't bring everything react just for the sake of answering