# How to find out when window.location changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax function that performs a filter and then changes the url.

How would I do the equivalent of the following:

```
$(window.location).change(function() {
    alert('hello');
})
```

Comment: So when the user navigates away from the page?

Comment: No, the user is still on the page. The querystring is just changing. For example: /tasks/?task_status=problem --> /tasks/?task_status=problem&definition=mastering

Comment: More accurately, when `window.location.search` changes.

Comment: I'd say the best you can do is working with timers for checking every fix intervals

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes

Comment: @David542 Are you using [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) or just setting `window.location` directly? You may want the [`popstate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate).

Comment: Have a look here http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjavascript

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have a look at the history API. You can use the `onhashchange` event to detect that change.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' `

Comment: @David542 What version of jQuery are you using? You can use `.bind()` instead for this with versions [older than 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

If you change location, browser stop all of script and don't trigger change function, you can use only unload event of document when use change the location, check it here http://api.jquery.com/unload/ and if you only change bookmark then only handle `hashchange` event, you can find sample jquery plugin here http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/..