# ASP.NET MVC abandon session when leaving the current page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to fire `Session.Abandon()` when a user leaves the page he is watching.
If the user just refreshes the page session must be kept.
I tried to do this client-side firing an ajax call when unloading the page `window.addEventListener("unload", function(e)...` but I'm not able to distinguish if the user is just refreshing the page or is leaving it.
I'm currently usuing ASP.NET MVC5.
Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 5):

There is no straight-forward way to do this... The question is: why would you want to do this anyway? Feels like bad design to me.

You could handle some [navigate event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3522090/993547) and check if the domain is the same as you currently have. If not, fire an AJAX call to abandon the session. Make sure to make that call a HTTP POST with a CSRF token to be sure not to be vulnerable to CSRF.

Comment: To answer your question: I need to keep in session a list of items that can be managed interating with the page (like a single page application). When the user clicks on "save" button data are persisted on DB.
If you've a different approach to do this it will be very nice.

Comment: Okay. This answer could be helpful to you in that case.

Comment: I tried to add a listener for the popstate event as explained in your link but seems not working on chrome. Can you post a working example that does what you suggested, please?