# Trigger event when user clicks the browsers back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, navigation

Is it possible with jquery to trigger a function when the user clicks the browsers back button.
I have a lightbox/widget that when open fills the window when it is open. There is a close button etc but this would be good if this closed if a user hit the back button by mistake.

I have this so far but the function doesnt seem to run at all

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('BACK PRESSED');
            var direction = data.state.direction;
            if (direction === 'back') {
                if(widgets.full_active){
                    $('.close', widgets.active_widget).click();
                    event.preventDefault();
                    console.log('CLOSE THIS');
                }
            }
            if (direction === 'forward') {
                // do something else
            }
        });
```

By not running this line at the start of the function **event.preventDefault();** should mean the page never changes

Comment: use window.onbeforeunload event instead.

Comment: ^ but note that the event also fires when the tab/window is closed, or the user navigates to another site. There's no way to know when the unload event was raised by a back button click alone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes same concept

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I do this using the native JavaScript API from the browser, like described here: [Manipulating the Broser History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

With jQuery, I see people usually using this plugin: [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/), although I have no idea what is it's status.

The event you're looking for is [onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate).

> A popstate event is dispatched to the window every time the active
>   history entry changes between two history entries for the same
>   document.