# Detect url changes from external source (Canny widget)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [the Canny widget](https://canny.io/docs/widget) in my website, and it tends to modify my URL. I am trying to detect these URL changes, but my code does not alert me to these changes (for instance, it fails to fire when I hit the Browser back button if it takes me from a post within the widget to a board within the widget).

```
componentWillMount() {
    addEventListener('hashchange', function() { console.log('url changed'); });
    addEventListener('popstate', function() { console.log('url changed'); });
  }
```

Any ideas for picking up these URL changes the widget is making?

EDIT: Example of how the widget changes the URL:

```
My URL: mywebsite.com/boards/boardToken

What Canny might change the URL to when selecting a post,
does not fire either event listed above: 
mywebsite.com/boards/boardToken/p/selected-post
```

Comment: In what way does the URL change? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event when window.location.href changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes)

Comment: Example provided. I feel like I checked out the other question linked before posting this here, but I will attempt it again nonetheless.