# Catch any JavaScript redirects

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer

How can you catch javascript redirects which were made by `document.location = url` in Puppeteer? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event when window.location.href changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to listen for ['domcontentloaded' event](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-domcontentloaded)?

```js
page.on('domcontentloaded', () => { console.log(page.url()); });
```