# Calling change event on browser back event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In .cshtml page,

```
<section>
    <label class="select">
        @if (itm.OutOfStock)
        {
            <select class="form-control" id="itm_SelectedQty" name="itm.SelectedQty" disabled="disabled">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => itm.SelectedQty, itm.QtyChoices, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
        }
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => itm.MenuItemId, new { @class = "itm_MenuItemId" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => itm.ItemAmount, new { @class = "itm_ItemAmount" })
        <i></i>
    </label>
</section>
```

And the following jQuery code is getting called, on change:

```
 $('.form-control').change(function () {

    var selectedQty = this.value;

 });
```

How can I call this same on change function, when someone clicks on browser's back button?

Comment: use this if applicable
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes

Answer (score 0):

You can't really tell that the back button was clicked, from the request...

One solution is to use [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history)

The other option is to add an `isDirty` variable to you page. This variable will be included in your request, so you can use it to detect if the page is dirty (i.e. back button has been clicked):

Add a hidden variable to your form:

```
/* I am using bootstrap, d-none would hide the input */
<input type="text" value="0" id="isDirty" class="d-none" />
```

Then in your JavaScript code (I am using jQuery), set the value of `isDirty` to 1

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var isDirty = $('#isDirty');

    if (isDirty.length) { //<-- is dirty is defined

        // if user click the back button, isDirty is 1, call your function here
        if (isDirty.val() === "1") {
            // call whatever function you want to run on back button click
        }
        else {
            isDirty.val("1");  // <-- set isDirty to 1
        }
    }
});
```