# notification about every change of URL

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

Is it possible to get (event) notification about every change of URL (without reloading page, like we can do with use `location.replaceState()`)?

More precisely: I don't change component or page. I just change URL for future.

**UPADATE Not elegant solution: manually triggering**

```
var popStateEvent = new PopStateEvent('popstate', { state: state });
dispatchEvent(popStateEvent);
```

Comment: What kind of notification?

Comment: Any notification e.g. event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event when window.location.href changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes)

Comment: Regrettably, no..

Comment: If you can listen the route change then, you can detect the url change. see if this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

You may need to create a service injectable to root and add a subject for it that get triggered in every onDestroy for each component.

in a service:

```
//imports here
export class TestService {
   pageChange$ = new Subject();
}
```

in all components where you want to trigger the change:

```
//imports
export class TestComponent implements OnDestroy {
//component properties
  constructor(private testSrv: TestService){}
  ngOnDestroy(){
    let notification = 'This page is getting closed';
    testSrv.pageChange$.next(notification);
  }
}
```

in a component where you want to receive the change:

```
//imports
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
//component properties
  constructor(private testSrv: TestService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    let notification = 'This page is getting closed';
    testSrv.pageChange$.subscribe(notification => {
       console.log(notification);
     });
  }
}
```

This is an overall idea of what you might do to solve your issue.

**Update**

If you want to just track url changes, you need to use `Router`:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit(){
   this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
        if(this.router.navigated){
           //do something here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe I wrote not precisely but I don't change component or page. I just change URL for future.

Comment: @patrycze I've left my answer as as and added an update section below it. Check it out and let me know.