# Disable browser history stack or force reload on back()/forward()

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I need to force a reload() on the server-side for a timer.

The issue we're encountering is the browser history stack allows users to navigate back and forth without hitting the server and we're losing the time spent on a tracked task. Kind of hacky, I know.

I thought something like this might be a start (it isn't working):

> ```
>     window.addEventListener('pageload', function () {
>         console.log('Page loaded via back/for button');
>     });
> ```

The caveat, is I can only reload() when the browser back/forward functions were used. The URI will change constantly via the UI, in which case it already invokes a request to the server.

EDIT | I tried this as well (capture the back/next event and force a reload or AJAX request to server to capture context change)

```
(function($) {

    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
        console.log(event);
    });


        // Second solution...
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
            console.log('URI changed');
        });

        const pushUrl = (href) => {
            history.pushState({}, '', href);
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('popstate'));
        };



})(jQuery);
```

Also not working, what am I missing?

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your scenario, but something like this in JavaScript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState could prevent certain pages from ever entering the history

Comment: Is there an event I can capture when the back()/forward() operation occur? I could then just notify the server the URI has changed without commanding a full reload()

Comment: There is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes