# Track page forwarding javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forwarding

**Problem:**

I want to track all the forwards to another page, e. g. when a user clicks on a link leading to the site https://example.com/ I want to track this event. The forward should also be tracked when calling:

```
location.href="https://example.com".
```

The code should look something like this:

```js
$(window).on("forward???", function(event) {
    //This is just some pseudo code
    console.log(event.href);
});
```

**Expected Output:**

The program should output the link to which is forwarded to, e. g.:

```
https://example.com/page1
```

Is it possible to track such an event using jquery or vanilla javascript?

**Purpose:**

I'm looking for a solution to track all forwards to another page so I don't have to implement it for each link or location.href seperately.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Answer (score 2):

You could track clicks on any a tags.

```js
$('a').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('href')); // or any other tracking logic

  return true; // continue with link
});
```

Comment: But what if it's not a link (in the a-tag)? e. g. if I forward using javascript (maybe on the click of a button)

Comment: But what is the logic for the button? Buttons generally don't redirect to new page (except if part of the form).

Comment: Suppose I have two forms on a website. Each one has a submit button. I make an ajax call on the submit and then forward to another page. I just want  to log each forward.

Comment: Can you also share the code where you forward to another page? Are you using window.location?

Comment: There are few options mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes

But if you can control the code, why don't you call tracking code before you use location.href?

Comment: Cause I've written quite a lot of code and don't want to update each bit. But thanks, that link helped a lot.