# Trigger a function when a certain value changes in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eventtrigger

In `React.js` if I want to trigger a function when a certain value changes I would use the `useEffect` hook and pass it a dependency array containing the value that should cause that function to trigger:

```
const [myState,setMyState] = useState("some-value");

useEffect(
   () => {
      someFunctionToTrigger();
   }, [theValue]
);
```

However I'd like to acheive that in pure JavaScript, more specifically I want to know when my `location.href` changes so I could call a function every time it changes:

```
let location_href = location.href;

// everytime location.href changes I want to call a function so I need the equivalent of useEffect
```

Note that using a `Proxy` doesn't work with `location`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listening for variable changes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript)

Comment: This may answer your question - [Event when window.location.href changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes)