# Subscribing to browser url bar changes performed with location.go/location.replaceState

Tags: angular, url, rxjs, observable

I'm looking to track URL changes made via location.go(..) or location.replaceState(..) and ideally want to use an Observable for this.

Since these methods bypass Angular's router, I can't use router navigation events for detection.

Is there a way to achieve this with standard Angular features, like subscribing to an existing Observable?

From what I understand, a potential solution could be to wrap the Location service in a custom service, like SubscribableLocationService, where calls to go/replaceState also emit on a Subject or BehaviorSubject (like $currentUrl.next(newUrl)), allowing subscription to $currentUrl.

**..but is this custom wrapper really necessary, or is there a more straightforward Angular way to do this?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event when window.location.href changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes)

Comment: it might! tomorrow or the day after tomorrow I'll test it, and will let you know. Thank you a lot fo this reference