# How to raise an event on find bar text change

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get the find bar text in a browser and is there any way to raise an event when the text is changed inside findbar.
My Intention behind this is assigning the value to a Local variable on findbar change.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by find bar? Do you mean the address bar or the bar for searching through a page you get on Ctrl-F?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's going to help but here are two other posts that might help.

[Handle URL anchor change event in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161906/handle-url-anchor-change-event-in-js)

[How can I detect an address bar change with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930927/how-can-i-detect-an-address-bar-change-with-javascript)

Comment: Cant see how this can get the value entered in the find/search bar

Comment: this is really not answer of the question