# Capture the removal of a hash

Tags: javascript, hash

I have attached certain actions to the existence of a URL hash in order to mimic traditional 'back' behavior.

The trouble is, if you go back from the hash, the hash is removed from the URL string, but the **JavaScript** doesn't pick up that that hash has gone.

How can I make it pick up the removal of the hash?

Comment: Try the hashchange event (`onhashchange`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poll `window.location.href` to detect changes. Use the change to work out what needs to be reverted. see [How can I detect an address bar change with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1930927/697081)

Answer (score 1):

Usually clicks go first,  then location changes.
After a click is a good idea to set TimeOut
to get an updated window.location.hash as shown below.

```
    $(".nav").click(function(){
    setTimeOut(function(){
      updatedHash = location.hash
    },100);
    });
```

or you can listen for the location with:

```
    window.onhashchange = function(evt){
       updatedHash = "#" + evt.newURL.split("#")[1]
    };
```

I wrote a jQuery plugin that does something like what you want to do. https://github.com/rgarro/Route32 It's a simple anchor router.

Answer (score 0):

check the `window.location.hash` string, it will return the hash part of your url