# Detect url change in site with HistoryAPI

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am write browser extension for vk.com. This site use historyAPI to change url in adress bar and load content with ajax. I need detect URL change in my extension, and don't know how =( onhashchange don't work. In arsenal i am have jquery. Ssory for my english and please help.

Comment: I believe that onhashchange may only fail if you are not on modern browser. This question probably may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930927/how-can-i-detect-an-address-bar-change-with-javascript

Comment: can you show us some code you've tried so far.

Comment: Shure http://pastebin.com/QnKJWn1v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a [progress listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners) in Firefox, `onLocationChange` method of the listener will be called for each change in the address bar. Please do not use polling - this will both waste CPU resources and drain battery in laptops.

[`chrome.webNavigation` API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html) provides a similar mechanism in Chrome. The [`onCommitted` event](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onCommitted) should fire when the URL changes.

Comment: What about Internet Explorer?

Comment: @dSquared: Internet Explorer doesn't have anything one could call extensions. Which is probably the reason why it isn't mentioned in the tags of this question.

Comment: An excellent point... my bad; thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you. But sad about IE =(