# Can I get an event when the address bar is modified?

Tags: javascript, html, events, browser

Is there any `event` which is generated when the address bar text is modified by the user? Like, when user tries to execute javascript through address bar.

I have checked all the `window` events, none of them relate to address bar.

**Update**

As per the comments, I have tried `window.onhashchange`, but it only fires if the hash changes, not for the actual URL.

The reason I need this to find a way to stop the user from executing javascript from address bar. So, the timer solution won't work either.

Is there any way I can catch the `onbeforeunload` and set the location back to the previous one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930927/how-can-i-detect-an-address-bar-change-with-javascript

Comment: It is not a duplicate, the other question is for `hash` change and it won't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such event (native I mean)

Here is a subject about how to make an event out of window's location changes (uses setInterval):

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1520-Binding-Events-To-Non-DOM-Objects-With-jQuery.htm

If you're using ajax, you might wanna check this out:

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Comment: I have seen the one using setInterval(), was looking at something already available in the platform.

Comment: Also, setinverval only works if want any changes in hash, still staying in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

There is none such trick, but maybe the `window.onbeforeunload` can help you. With this you can know at least, when the user leaves your page.

See an example of it here: https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm

Comment: Still, even if I catch the `onbeforeunload` event, I won't be able to stop the user, right?

Comment: You can not force him to, but you can ask him to. There will be a window displayed asking him, whether he really wants to leave.

Comment: Can I redirect the page back to the original when `onbeforeunload` fires?

Comment: This depends on the browser that is used. In all newer ones: I think you can't.