# AngularJS interceptor not putting JWT Bearer in every request of node.js app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I put a JWT authentication system in a node app.

I used an interceptor to put the Bearer in every request. It works well if I call a restricted route within Angular or if I curl and specify the token in the header.
But if I enter the restricted route directly in my address bar, it doesn't work. There is no Bearer in the header, it doesn't go through the interceptor.

Here is my interceptor (client-side):

```
angular.module('myApp).factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $window) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if ($window.localStorage.token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.localStorage.token;
      }
      return config;
    },
    responseError: function (rejection) {
      if (rejection.status === 401) {
        // handle the case where the user is not authenticated
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
});
```

Here is my restricted route (server-side):

```
router.get('/restricted', expressJwt({secret: 'SecretStory'}), function(req, res) {
  res.json({
      name: 'You are allowed here !!'
    });
})
```

**How to make the bearer to be added to my request header on every request, even in typing the restricted route directly into the address bar?**

Answer (score 2):

When you enter a URL directly in the address bar you are circumventing your Angular code and, as you've discovered, the interceptor will not run.

You *could* try [detecting when the URL in the address bar changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930927/how-can-i-detect-an-address-bar-change-with-javascript) and try to work around the problem, but I would recommend against this.

Instead, I would approach this problem server-side by detecting a `GET /restricted` request with an `Accept` header of `text/html` (anything that is not `application/json` really). Then respond with HTML that includes your Angular code and request `/restricted` again using `application/json` when the page loads. This would be a good way to distinguish between explicit URL navigation and Angular requests and offers better hypermedia support to your API.

Comment: Ok, I see what is your solution. But I do not know if it is possible to implement it.

If I detect the accept header:

`router.get('/restricted', expressJwt({secret: secret}) , function(req, res){
if (req.headers["accept-language"] != 'application/json') {
//Called from URL navigation
}
res.json({ name: 'You are allowed here !!' });
}) `

It is after the verification of the jwt, I don't thinks it is possible to have different behavior for the same route before the verification of the jwt.

Comment: Instead of `res.json` you can call `res.send`, `res.redirect`, etc. http://expressjs.com/api.html