# If entering a specific url address submit a form js

Tags: javascript, html

I want to submit a form when entering a specific address on the url bar manually , is it possible? something like this

```
if(urlbar== "mylink.com/admin" && event.keyCode === 13)
    {
       myform.submit();
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean when the user manually pastes in a different address into their browser and navigates away from your page?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot detect events in the browser's address bar.

You cannot detect the URL the user is about to navigate to if the navigation is caused by something outside the page (e.g. you could use a `click` event on an `a` element and then read it's `href` but you could not use `onbeforeunload` and get the URL typed into the address bar).

Answer (score -1):

Can use an interval.

```
 setInterval(function() {
      if(location.href == "mylink.com/admin") {
          myform.submit();
      }
  }, 1000);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1930942/3093731